# Not able to capture HTTPS request - mobile performance testing

Tags: android, https, jmeter

Android TAB and JMeter is being used to capture/ Record the application flow. But the HTTPS reqests are not capturing in JMeter. I turned off Jmeter and enabled Charles Proxy and did the recording again. After recording the same application flow in Charles I took all the HTTPS requests and placing in Jmeter. It took longer time because am doing the recording twice.

Is there any other way to capture the HTTPS traffic via JMETER?

Apprecaite your help and share your suggestions.

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 2):

First use JMeter Recording Template
Then start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it will generate in jmeter/bin folder, a file called  `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` . 
Copy file to your android device and install it as CA Certificate.
See [How do I install a user certificate?](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841102-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-an-android-device) thread for more details.

The certificate has limited life time (defaults to 7 days) but you can extend it by setting in user.properties

> proxy.cert.validity=Number of days

Now the problem you'll face in Android >= 7.0 is that applications only use by default System installed Certificates.

So you'll need to ask developper of application to modify the APK, see why [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Edit manifest and add :

> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

You'll get:

...

Then add in res/xml/network_security_config.xml this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>  
       <base-config>  
             <trust-anchors>  
                 <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->  
                 <certificates src="system" />  
                 <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->  
                 <certificates src="user" />  
            </trust-anchors>  
       </base-config>  
 </network-security-config>
```

Note that this is needed whatever tool you use (Neoload, LoadRunner, ...)

Comment: What should be specified in the HTTPS domain field,if i am testing the performance of  an Android application?...

Answer (score 1):

Certain Android versions support only HTTP proxying out of the box, you may have to install 3rd-party software like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) in order to be able to configure HTTPS Proxy.

Easier option is using [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) solution, if you have doubts regarding correctness of your JMeter side of things configuration you can test Mobile Recorder.